# How to dynamically allocate memory in 2D array and store values?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to allocate memory in a 2D array dynamically, but I don't know what is wrong.

**Error**
let input is

```
2 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ........
```

then program crashes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int N,M;
    int i,j;
    scanf("%d %d",&N,&N);

    int **A = (int **)malloc(N*sizeof(int *));

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        A[i] = (int *)malloc(M*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<M;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<M;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have provided no evidence that you are wrong, or even what you mean by "wrong".

Comment: Whats the problem ? It seems OK. Except casting `malloc`

Comment: _I don't know what is wrong_ And how do you know something is wrong? Do you have any compile error,crash, unexpected result?

Comment: if i want to create an array of size 2 x 2 then it stores more than its size, I think scanf runs infinitely.

Comment: How did you define `N` and `M`?

Comment: Even though this isn't a 2D array, this code should work fine. You are probably not posting the faulty part. So post a complete code example.

Comment: @Samer Tufail Please do NOT change the code in questions except for formatting. Doing so changes its meaning.

Comment: So __what__ is wrong? Did you not get the expected output? Did it crash? Did it format your hard disk? Did it set your house on fire?

Comment: after providing values my program crashes, input is N=2,  M=2 and then array is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ......, it does not stops.

Comment: N,M are input by user? Did you check if they have correct values?

Comment: Your problem is in a piece of code you haven't posted.  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.  That means a complete piece of code that others can copy and paste, compile, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: `int N,M; ... 
    scanf("%d %d",&N,&N);` --> missing scan of `M`

Comment: @VikasGautam I hope you understand now why it is important to post a [MCVE].

Comment: `int (*A)[N][M] = malloc(sizeof *A);` is an example of dynamically allocate memory for a 2D array.  Yet I think OP does not want a 2D array, but an array of pointers to pointers to `int`.

Comment: @VikasGautam don't make corrections in your question, as otherwise the question doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: @interjay I wasnt sure if it was a typo or deliberately missed out. Apologies.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks for your advice, now i know here we should not ask  about logic but whole program is needed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said problem is in scanning `N` and `M` variables.

Change

```
scanf("%d %d",&N,&N);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&N);
scanf("%d",&M);
```

and you are fine.

Problem was you were reading `N` twice while didnt read an `M` which was used uninitialized.

Non-static variables (local variables) are *indeterminate*. Reading them prior to assigning a value results in undefined behavior.

---

You should free all your allocated memory

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    free(A[i]);
}
free(A);
```

and dont cast `malloc()`'s return value becouse

- Its reduntand
- Adding the cast may mask failure to include the header `stdlib.h`, in which the prototype for malloc is found
- If the type of the pointer is changed, one must fix all code lines where `malloc()` was called and cast

---

Next time if you cannot find a `bug`, try to use debugger and look what exactly is happening, you can see variable values, where would you clearly see that `M` is uninitialized and didnt change after `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
scanf("%d %d",&N,&N);
```

When you read in the array dimensions, you read into `N` twice and never read into `M`.  As a result, the contents of `M` are indeterminate, and attempting to read that value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Fix this to input a value for `M`:

```
scanf("%d %d",&N,&M);
```

Comment: Why was this perfectly correct answer downvoted?

Comment: wow - a downvote!! Who on earth did that?